# lightbox type solution to zoom in on code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, lightbox, yii

Ok I am fishing here...

Is there some solution (PHP / jQuery) that I can use to zoom in on my code?  Something like lightbox does for images.

I would like to zoom in on dynamic code where I am using Yii's CListView, but can pull this code with a foreach statement also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it is the lightbox idea expanded to variety of formats http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: Thanks, I can get the same functionality with jQuery Dialog, just looking for something more robust that will allow me to nav through an array like lightbox(alternatives) does with images.

Comment: @enfield I think you will have to customize one of these approaches to do that.  Though it might not be to hard to strip out the image code and replace it with code to display your array.